# OpenCV2 imshow image display not working as I expected

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to display some images using OpenCV library. (for further usages, such as CV techniques.. etc)

Anyway, I managed to display an 'normal image' with simple codes like below

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("rebecca_ferguson.jpg")
cv2.imshow('test', im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

However, if I generate a random image, which all pixels have 0 ~ 255, I guess the program should display an arbitrary/grayscale image, but it doesn't, only a black image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

b = np.random.rand(500, 500) * 255
b = b.astype(int)

cv2.imshow('test', b)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]
Why does it happen?

This is very important, whenever I touch an image, it only shows black image like this...

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `b = np.random.rand(500, 500) * 255 * 256`, by default [`imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#cv2.imshow) will divide by 256 if the dtype is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit int or `b = np.random.rand(500, 500)` this will multiply by 255 automatically if the dtype is float

Comment: `b.astype(int)` -- Given that you seem to want values between 0 and 255, you probably want `np.uint8`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to EdChum and Dan Mašek!! Both solutions solved my problem! Frankly speaking, I am a newbie to this field, so I didn't know what to do at all. Thanks a lot, again!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code i works fine for me

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

b = np.random.rand(500, 500) * 255
b = b.astype(int)

cv2.imshow('test', b)
cv2.waitKey()
```

and the output is:

[image]

Comment: How exactly does a script which does not even import matplotlib output a matplotlib chart? The expected output would be a GUI window showing a grayscale image, but with this code it will look all black due to reasons already explained by EdChum in a comment on the question.

Comment: it ran on jupyter notebook. i have import matplotlib in the previous tab, sorry i forgot to mention. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an answer